# .123 extension doesn't treated as textfile

Tags: text, file-format

The file became lotus spreadsheet when the file extension is .123. I want it to be treated as textfile only since the lotus is adding unecessary characters.

Edit: It is only adding extra characters when opening in libreoffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, .123 file extension is recognized as a spreadsheet file and the system will try to open the file with application supporting spreadsheet (like lotus / libreoffice).

First you need to change the default opening type for this file extension. That can be done by,

1. Right click on the file and select properties -> Select "Open with" tab.
   [image]
2. Select "Show Other applications" -> choose the text editor of your choice -> Press "Set as default" button [image]

This will always makes the file with .123 extension to be recognized as a text file.